# Cannot login to stackoverflow.com

Tags: support, login

On the login page it says

> If you don't already have an account on any of the above

But using Firefox, there are no above. Now I'm in IE and can login. I did delete all browser data associated with Stack Overflow and removed all addons from Firefox.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Disable AdBlock or similar addons in Firefox.